# How does set membership relate to equality?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, inequality

Suppose $x\in\{1\}\,$, would this be equivalent to $x=1$?
Similarly, would $x\in[1,2]\,$ be equivalent to $1\le x\le2\,$?

Comment: yes,both statements are true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, by definition $x\in \{1\}$ if $x$ is an element of the set $\{1\}$ and because $1$ is the only element of this set, we must have $x = 1$. Also, note that $[1,2] := \{a \in \mathbb{R}: 1 \le a \le 2\}$ so $x \in [1,2]$ implies $1 \le x \le 2$.

Answer (score 0):

Your main question is on how set membership relates to equality. The answer lies in the ZFC Axioms of Set Theory. In particular, the Axiom of Extension tells you exactly how two sets are equal to each other.

There are different formulations of that axiom that can be found in various sources. For example, [1] contains a rather simplistic formulation of the axiom and [2] begins to formalize it way more. That's because [1] only spends one chapter on Axiomatic Set Theory while [2] is entirely ABOUT Axiomatic Set Theory. I will state the axiom as it has been stated in [1].

**Axiom of Extension:**

Two sets are equal iff they have the same elements. That is, if $A$ and $B$ are sets, then $A = B \iff \forall x: x \in A \iff x \in B$.

On the other hand, the axiom has been stated in a slightly different way in [2]:

**Axiom of Extensionality:**

$(\forall x)(x \in A \iff x \in B) \implies A = B$

In other words, we can say that two sets are equal only by comparing the objects that they have and determining if they're the same or not. Despite the slight difference in the two formulations, set membership remains an integral part of the definition of set equality.

Of course, there's more to say about this. Keep in mind that the notion of an object belonging to a set is a primitive one. That is, it's not defined in Set Theory. I would say more about this but I think that I will leave you to read about this from the sources that I have provided.

I should also say that 'equivalent' has a very different meaning from the 'equal' in Set Theory. In particular, two sets $A$ and $B$ are said to be equivalent if there is a bijective mapping that exists between them. That differs from equality, which is defined entirely by set membership.

Sources:

[1] Fundamentals of Mathematics by Bernd Schroder

[2] Axiomatic Set Theory by Patrick Suppes